# rank pandas dataframe by row instead of by column?

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to rank a pandas dataframe by row instead of by column?

Ranking should be highest to smallest.

Example data:

```
Item    Apple    Orange    Pear    Watermelon     Grape
Weight     72        94      55            34        78
```

I would like to place the rank within the dataframe such that my output is:

```
Item    Apple    Orange    Pear    Watermelon     Grape
Weight     72        94      55            34        78
Rank        3         1       4             5         2
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one row `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with `ascending=False` and `axis=1`:

```
df.loc['rank'] = df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False).astype(int).squeeze()
```

Or is possible select row and use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df.loc['Rank'] = df.loc['Weight'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
        Apple  Orange  Pear  Watermelon  Grape
Item                                          
Weight     72      94    55          34     78
rank        3       1     4           5      2
```